# What is the difference between "the game is so fun" with "fun" as an adjective and "the game is so fun" with "fun" as a noun?

Tags: difference, phrases

What is the difference between "**the game is so fun**" with "**fun**" as an adjective and "**the game is so fun**" with "**fun**" as a noun?

I don't know if "**fun**" is an adjective or a noun in "**the game is so fun**".

Sometimes, people say "**the game is so much fun**", then I can figure out  "**fun**" here is a noun.

But, when people say "**the game is really fun**", I can figure out  "**fun**" here is an adjective.

Comment: The use of **fun** as an adjective (so fun) is modern and informal. It's more usual to say "The game is **such fun**".

Comment: Maybe the confusion comes just because "fun" can be both noun or adjective. I see no confusion about "The truck is so red."

Comment: @AndyBonner Right, and you can't say: the truck is so redness, can you?

Comment: @KateBunting I disagree; it's modern, but not informal, and "such fun" sounds stilted, as though you're affecting an old-timey accent.

Comment: @Hearth - Well, I can see from your profile that you are a very different demographic from me. Oxford dictionaries labels 'fun' as an adjective 'Informal'. I (UK, 70+) would say _such fun_ without any affectation.

Comment: @KateBunting For others' reference seeing this, I'm in my late 20s in the US. It could be a generational difference, or it could be a British/American difference, or both. I should have mentioned that in the earlier comment.

Comment: @Hearth - saying that something is "so fun" is not common in the UK. It sounds really off to me.  I have heard it, but mostly from Americans.   You can do a google ngram search using  "so fun,such fun,so much fun". The differences are quite stark between Am.Eng and Br. Eng, particularly as far as "so fun" is concerned.  And "so much fun" is much more common in both Am.Eng and Br.Eng.

Comment: @Hearth - See [this blog](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2023/08/so-fun-such-fun.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is a tricky question.

Originally, "fun" was a noun only.  It then retained its grammatical status as a noun but begun to be used in phrases that are the semantic equivalent of adjectives.  It has now become construed grammatically as an adjective by some speakers in some situations, but the process is not fully complete.

> What is the difference between "the game is so fun" with "fun" as an adjective and "the game is so fun" with "fun" as a noun?
>
> I don't know if "fun" is an adjective or a noun in "the game is so
> fun".

Used with "so" in this usage, "fun" must be an adjective.

For conservative speakers, "fun" is almost always treated grammatically as a noun; whereas innovative speakers sometimes use it as an adjective in some constructions.  Conservative speakers would say "so much fun" or "such fun."

The one borderline exception is when "fun" is used alone as a predicate noun/adjective, as in "That was fun."  Here the grammatical status of "fun" is ambiguous.  Conservative speakers probably feel this phrase uses "fun" as a noun and is merely a reduction of "That was a lot of fun." Innovative speakers probably feel that same phrase uses "fun" as an adjective and is the equivalent of "That was (so) fun.

> But, when people say "the game is really fun", I can figure out "fun"
> here is an adjective.

The use of "really" doesn't guarantee that "fun" is an adjective.  Conservative speakers could view this as a reduction of "the game is really a lot of fun."

If writing or speaking formally, you should generally use "fun" only in contexts where it is unambiguously a noun; otherwise, you could risk sounding slangy.  For instance, I think only few speakers would accept a phrase like "that was a too fun party" in normal writing or formal speech and would require "that party was too much fun."  Younger or innovative speakers, however, might also say "that party was too fun."

Answer (score 2):

One reason why this is confusing is, some of these little words can have multiple parts of speech. Let's look at "This game so much fun!"

- **so** is an adverb which modifies the adjective "much." [(Definition 2 - "To the extent or degree".)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so)
- **much** is an adjective telling us the amount of the noun "fun."
- **fun** in this case is a noun.

Let's look at "This game is so fun!"

- **so** is again an adverb, modifying "fun".
- **fun** here is a [predicate adjective](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/predicate_adjectives.htm), describing the subject, "game."

Most simply, if we make the second sentence as simple as possible, we are saying ***"The game is fun."*** You can modify that adjective "fun" with an adverb to alter the meaning of the sentence, to tell us how much fun the game is:

- "The game is so fun!"
- "The game is really fun!"
- "The game is such fun!"
- "The game is somewhat fun."
- "The game is hardly fun."

Comment: Very well done. :)